# c# - TableAdapter.Fill() + Dataset.Clear() increasing memory

Tags: c#, memory, dataset

I got a simple test application with 2 buttons and a DataGridView.

Button 1: TableAdapter1.Fill(DataSet1.TEST);
Button 2: DataSet1.Clear();

Clicking button 1 will load the data from database, memory usage increases from ~25mb to ~100mb.
Clicking button 2 removes the data - atleast it is no longer viewable in the DataGridView.

But memory usage stays at ~100mb.

What is missing here?

Comment: There is no problem here. Using some memory is OK, it's what programs do. Your expectations of how/when an app releases memory are wrong.

Comment: when I do the following:

Click button 1
Click button 2
Click button 1 
Click ...
and so on ...

memory will increase step by step. that isn't really what a program should do.

Comment: Yes, that is what most programs do. It will level off. It isn't a problem until you get OOM exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You are not missing anything .Clearing from dataset doesn't remove it from the actual memory.The reference only is just removed

Comment: what element / instance need to be "cleared" to remove it from memory?

Comment: You can't 'remove' anything. Why do you think that's necessary?

Comment: the CLR manages the memory. you could probably try doing  DataSet1 = null and do  GC.Collect () though it is not advisable always.